# Continous scroll with xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

I would like to emulate the function of a mouse-wheel with keys using xmodmap. For this reason I mapped Alt+Shift+J and Alt+Shift+K to mousewheel up and down like this:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down Pointer_Button5"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K Up Pointer_Button4"
```

That works fine as in that I can scroll up/down by repeatedly pressing those key combinations. But I would like to be able to hold those keys and have it scroll continously  without having to press the keys again and again.

Is there any way to do this?